# HTML form post to Google Docs spreadsheet

Tags: html, forms, google-docs

Is there a way for an HTML form to directly post into a Google Docs spreadsheet? The spreadsheet must not be publically readable or modified by others.

I'd like to do something like:

```
<form action="https://google-docs-url" method="POST">
     ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you must be using Google Sheets API.
You will find [more details here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values).

Comment: Seems super low level, like I'd need to specify the row and column of each insert? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, this is the way. And you won't be able to send the data directly, you have to prepare the data you send with php, then you can send it to API.